# How setting up direction of object axis x and z after a rotation around object axis Y?

Tags: three.js, rotation

I have rotated a group called pivot following this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/of1vfhzz/1/

And applying the function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians) from this thread:

[Rotation around an axis three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660395/rotation-around-an-axis-three-js)

the function is showed belove

```
function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians) {
                rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
                rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);

                object.matrix.multiply(rotObjectMatrix);

                object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
            }`
```

The meshes inside pivot, rotate in the right way but also the axis orientation change and since I want move these object along the z axis, how can I do? There is a way to set up, after a rotation ,the z axis as before, without changing the rotation of this group of objects?

Comment: Tip: `rotateAroundObjectAxis()` is outdated and incredibly inefficient. Do not use it.

Comment: What I could use?

Comment: `Object3D.rotateOnWorldAxis()` or `Object3D.rotateOnAxis()` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953608/rotate-object-on-specific-axis-anywhere-in-three-js-including-outside-of-mesh/32038265#32038265.